# Carthrob and Inventory Management

Tags: cartthrob

hoping someone can help!

The site I am working on is for a performing arts dance and music studio where users can register online for classes by semester or quarter (two avail at a time).

I'm having some trouble wrapping my head around how I could make inventory work for their dance and drama classes. Classes are offered and available to sign up for by Semester or Quarter. What I need is for the inventory to adjust automatically according to what the user signed up for. So if they sign up for the whole semester, I need to make sure the inventory under quarter 1 and 2 both get deducted. That way if someone signs up for just one of the quarters, the class won't get over filled when a full semester is registered for. Likewise, the inventory will need to get deducted from the full semester sign-up option if one of the quarters is registered for (so that specific quarter, and the whole semester needs to get reduced by 1). But the other quarter available will still have a spot. Does that make sense?

If I can't get this to work right, I'm afraid it might be too big of a pain for my client to manage all these classes and will be more work than necessary - also could be tough to manually track the inventory for all their classes. Any insight or ideas into this greatly appreciated!

FWIW, I'm not a php programer by any means, but can work with basic existing scripts. I also have an intermediate knowledge and understanding of jquery and javascript if that might need to get used as a solution, however I can't and don't write my own scripts.

Thanks in advance!
Valerie

Answer (score 1):

I'd have each Semester (Quarter) as separate products, then use the multi add to cart tag so customer can select which ones they want to purchase.